# Алгоритмы обработки данных в метро

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм

В метро, когда мы подносим карточку к терминалу, у нас меньше чем за секунду загорается либо красный, либо зеленый свет. То есть, терминал за такое короткое время должен проверить, не находится ли ID нашей карточки в стоп-листе многомиллионной базы. Либо я плохо понимаю (я вообще не знаю) как работают терминалы в метро, либо есть какой-то алгоритм, который позволяет все это делать так быстро. Есть ли ссылки, где рассказывают про то, как работает терминал в метро (именно внутри) или про то, какой там алгоритм используется? Подскажите, пожалуйста, буду благодарен.

Comment: Почитайте что нибудь по основам баз данных. В любых БД используются _индексы_, которые обычно представлены как _двоичное дерево поиска_ (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) количество требуемых операций для поиска по такому дереву составляет двоичный логарифм от размера БД. Скажем для 100 млн карточек это всего 28 шагов.